# How do i integrate Braintree paypal payment android sdk?

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I am looking for a **brain-tree pay pal integration**(online resource)for my **android** project. This is my first time, that i am doing payment gateway integration.So i found braintree sdk documentations little difficult for me to understand. So,please anyone knows good online resourses for **braintree payment integration for android**?

Comment: check this example for Braintree Papal integration using android sdk >> https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2019/01/paypal-integration-in-android-using.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a question to help integrate an SDK would attract Downvotes. Try doing self study and research. However, as I understand your situation, I would help you to understand the document.

Link to document : [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/android/v2)

1. At first, create an account and get the API key that needs to be integrated. Follow this [link](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/paypal/setup-guide) to clearly understand how to create an account.
2. Once the information required is obtained, integrate the dependency

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
   }
3. After integrating the dependencies, just use the snippets provided in the link [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2#browser-switch-setup)

and you are all set to test using the sample test key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have successfully integrated Braintree using REST API Check out the git project
I have used retrofit to get a token from our server and that token is send to braintree API which sends me a nonce(It a token for payment) than this nonce is send back to our server tada payment is done
https://github.com/SarhanBax/Braintree-Using-Retrofit.git